# Knockout ViewModel separation, whats the general approach/best practice?

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel, dry, separation-of-concerns

I just started messing with Knockout JS, and I have the following scenarion (example).

I have a list of tourists, and that list has CRUD methods - all works great. Now, when I click a tourist, a more detailed description shall be presented - this is a new AJAX call to the server for that info.

My question is, should I have 1 Master view model that contains my `TouristsViewModel` and `TouristsInfoViewModel` - which means that the `TouristsViewModel` should be coupled with the master in order to modify the `TouristsInfoViewModel`, or should my `TouristsViewModel` instantiate the `TouristsInfoViewModel` and call `ko.applyBindings`?

I've looked at [Knockout-postbox](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox), but I'd like to avoid having to introduce too many 3rd party plugins.

To summarize: What's the general approach to separating views and viewmodels while being able to share data between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a general approach.

1. Invest your time in to learning about AMD and require.js is a great library for just that.
2. Keep your viewmodels separate and don't couple them.
3. knockout-postbox, amplify.js pub/sub work great in communicating with each other.
4. Look at a Single Page Application framework. Durandal is a great option.
5. If you are not planning to use Durandal or a SPA, even then, create a separate module that will handle your binding with knockout.
6. Each view should have a corresponding viewmodel.
7. Separate out your ajax calls in to modules of its own. ex: touristsRepository.js could be a module that is going to make all the ajax calls for you.
8. Work with promises. Q.js or jquery's deferred promises will help you out. Your repositories should return promises.
9. Your viewmodels should be just that... in essence, it should hold state and provide view interaction handlers. The model should be it's own file. The ViewModel can then hold the model data.
10. The model data should be retrieved only via the repositories.

I think this would be a decent approach and something that will work for you.

**EDIT - Adding more based on the comment.**

1) You can use shimming and exports in requirejs to load ko validation plugin, instead of using define. Unless you are not using requirejs to load it in the first place.

2) Using a pub/sub is not coupling. Coupling happens when one module depends completely on another's functionality or existence. Considering MasterViewModel is directly communicating with another viewmodel is coupling. In a pub/sub scenario, your one viewmodel (call it Persons.js) is say saving a person object. Once it saves, it is supposed to update the local cache. In this case, Persons.js, after it saves, sends out a message saying "Person saved" and pass any data it has. The ClearCache.js is the one responsible for clearing the cache. It is only listening for a "Person saved" message to take some action. The coupled way would be for Persons.js to instantiate ClearCache and call it's clearCache method directly. So, for Persons.js to exist, clearCache.js must exist. Where as, in pub/sub, even if clearCache.js does not exist, Persons.js can continue to exist.

3) An answer to this question totally depends on your application requirement. Typically, I have a intermediate module called binder.js. binder.js, listens for messages. So, let's say the user wants to see detailed info and clicks on a tourist. The TouristsViewModel is going to publish a message "Tourist Detail Requested" and pass a tourist id or some information. The binder, is listening for this, knows which viewmodel to instantiate and what action to take. That way, your ToursistsViewModel is completely ignorant of TouristsInfoViewModel. If on another view, you are listing all the tourists firstNames and lastNames and don't have to show details, you can re-use TouristsViewModel without having to unnecessarily bring in TouristsInforViewModel. A MasterViewModel in this case is not needed.

Your application sounds like a perfect candidate for a Single Page Application. Follow a "One View - One ViewModel" approach and a "Single Responsibility" approach. TouristsViewModel is showing only tourists, TouristInfoViewModel will show tourist info. Both of them have no clue about each other. I recently worked on a project which had similar requirements. Speakers, speaker details, Sessions, session details. None of my viewmodels know about the other. They are all managed via client side routes and hash change events.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! I am using Require already, and it's great, except for the fact that I had to wrap KO Validation plugin in a define() for it to work properly. Separating AJAX calls, good idea! I would probably name it touristsApi.js or touristsService.js, but whatever! Using Postbox/Amplify, that is not considered "coupling"? Also, as per my question, how would I manage the viewmodels? From a Master view model? Should the Master viewmodel instantiate all viewmodels at once? Please elaborate on that! +1 for now. :)

Comment: added more to my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Regarding the shimming of KO Validation, I tried it and didn't work, seems like a known bug (https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/issues/104) though, so I just went ahead and wrapped it in a define call and it's all good. Regarding `binder`, would that be my MasterViewModel in my scenario? Also, why do you recommend working with promises?

Comment: binder will it be its own module. You can have a main.js (bootstrapper) that will load it and keep it running right when your application starts (it wont be a Master View Model). Regarding promises, it is a much better way to deal with what we call the "callback hell". Consider this, you have only 1 success handler. You could be making more ajax calls based on your result from your first and so on and so forth. You will end up with a bunch of nested callbacks. with promise, you could do something like this Q.When(_firstAjaxCall).then(function(_firstAjaxResult){})

Comment: I got started using Durandal, and it's working excelent! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @SujeshArukil I appreciate your answer. Really wealth of information here. I agree most of points. I get pub\sub model but i think implementing this pattern for communicating between different js objects is a bit of overkill specially your point 3. Like on server side, we create objects and call methods on them incase we like to execute some functionality so can't we follow the same approach on client side? May be I am wrong. Please let me know your thoughts about this.

Comment: @Mandeep - pub/sub is not a solution for everything. There are places where I would definitely like to decouple my elements. Ex: Recently I created a form generator, which renders 100s of controls. Each control needed to let a corresponding save button know when it is loaded. Instead of the save button directly coupling with each control, I used pub sub to subscribe and every control to just notify. This way, I can add a new control and just publish a new message. This is where I see its use and unit testing, rather than load 100s of script files, I can just test if my js acts on a publish.